# Windows 10 Error After Logging in

Tags: user-accounts, microsoft-account

After logging in to our domain, some users have the following message appearing on their desktop:

> The current user (DOMAIN\Username) is unknown, please contact your system administrator.

Users can close this message and then appear to go on and work as normal.

Comment: Try deleting one of the domain profile on the server.  Delete same on workstation. Make a new domain profile on the server. Make same on workstation. Restart workstation. Test if the message goes away for this user.

Comment: @Andrew Cooper,  You forgot to specify if this message should be shown or not.  

Comment: You could use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to drag the bullseye on top of the message to find the process that issues it.

Comment: @harrymc - Why? The error message is being generated by the NT Kernel or some subcomponent of it. The author should contact their IT Administrator. If they are the IT Administrator, then they need to ask the person besides them, who is also an IT Administrator.  **This is situation where the problem exists within the AD domain.**

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, it's likely some startup that's mandated by the domain but is missing a component. My advice is in the hope that identifying the source will help identify the cause.